# vector usage in non-multithreaded application

Tags: java, collections

Vector vs Arraylist (in non-multithreading environment) – in which requirements we will use Vector (rather than ArrayList)
One I know : if the size of the collection has to be increased dynamically and very frequently as vector size increases by 100% and ArrayList 50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a single thread environment never user `Vector`. Its methods are "synchronized" and this makes it slow, very slow against `ArrayList`.

So event if the `ensureCapacity` behavior is different, and `Vector` increase the size by 2, the cost of every single operation cannot be compared with the cost of the `ArrayList` operations, that are more fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use vector because you have to `syncronized(also non-threaded environment) ,So Use ArrayList`

Vector is syncronized each operation ,do not whole operation and .....and its also deprecated...
[Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)